# gitk not finding addition of a string

Tags: git, gitk

I'm working in an enterprise git repository that was converted from a mercurial repository.

Normally, using gitk, I can find out how long ago a particular method was introduced by utilizing the "Find Commit" feature:

[image]

It seems a very straightforward feature.

What I'm trying to make sense of is: **When would this return no results?**

I've got a file with a method commented out. I want to see how long ago the method was introduced, but the find commit feature is claiming the method declaration line was never added to the file! I'm looking at the line in the file *right now*.

How can this be?

Comment: Did you try `gitk --all`